# plot3d - make the perspective of front and back planes equal

Tags: r, rgl, plot3d

I am migrating from gnuplot to R plotting.

In gnuplot when a 3d is rotated the front and back of the view line up, making the appearance of 2d plot.

In `plot3d()` the back plane appears narrower than the front plane of the view. So , it appears like there is a distance view (tunnel vision).

R plot3d showing narrowing of view:

[image: R plot3d showing narrowing of view]

gnuplot showing a 3d rotated so the front and back are one:

[image: gnuplot showing a 3d rotated so the front and back are one]

In my `plot3d()` the xyz axis are all set to 30 - a cube.

The question becomes: does `plot3d()` have way to not have a narrowing of the perspective ?

If the answer is 'no' - OK.

If the answer is 'yes' - just point me to a link or the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you are looking for an *isometric perspective*; try `par3d(FOV=0)`. From `?par3d`:

> ‘FOV’ real.  The field of view, from 0 to 179 degrees.  This
> controls the degree of parallax in the perspective view.
> Isometric perspective corresponds to ‘FOV = 0’.

Comment: Excellent - exactly what I wanted - Thanks

Comment: If this solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it.